# Reveal children of div by one by one on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML setup

```
<button>Start</button>
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <h2>First Div</h2>
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Second Div</h2>
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Third Div</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to press the start button and reveal the children divs of the div with the id of container one by one. So the first div would reveal itself on the first click and so on.

Here is the javascript that I have so far

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").addClass("hidden");

});
var count = $("#container > div").length;
$(":button").click(function() {
  if (count > 0) {

    count--;
  }
});
```

Any clever ideas?

Here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/afwonjr5/18/

I just want to hit the start button 3 times to reveal the 3 divs inside the container div.

Comment: please consider to give more specific details? And please include an fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Jquery you can simply try it like this.

```js
$("#container div").addClass("hidden");

var count = 0;
$("#start").click(function() {
  count++;
  $("#container div:nth-child("+count+")").toggle();
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="start">Start</button>
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <h2>First Div</h2>
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Second Div</h2>
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Third Div</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: or remove the `.hidden` class entirely. with JQuery `removeClass()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following code snippet :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#container > div').forEach(function(el) {
  el.classList.add("hidden");
});
var startButton = document.getElementById("hey")
startButton.onclick = function(e) {
  var arrDiv = Array.from(document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName("div"));
  var firstDivHidden = arrDiv.filter(function(div) {
    return div.classList.contains("hidden");
  })[0];
  if (firstDivHidden)
   firstDivHidden.classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="hey">Start</button>
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <h2>First Div</h2>
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Second Div</h2>
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Third Div</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps,

Best regards,